# HashiCorp Vault roles

Tags: hashicorp-vault, role-based-access-control

It's quite easy to create roles for policies and also list them in HashiCorp Vault:

```
vault write auth/jwt/role/myrolename ...
...
list auth/jwt/role
```

However, I can't find anything regarding how to display role details. Strange enough, the UI does not contain the section "roles".

Is it possible to access role details for an existing role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible as following:

```
vault read -format=json auth/jwt/role/ROLENAME
```